# Transition with initial css attribute value

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have the follow transition on `height` attribute -

```
.testDiv {
    height : 400px ; 
    -webkit-transition: height 2s,  -webkit-transform 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition:  height 2s, transform 2s;
}

.testDiv.hide {
    height : 0px ;
}
```

**[Here is its jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/8bbo9cfz/)**

Now , I want to get the same transition - from  `height` `0px` to `400px` , but such that it would start with `height:200px` immediately and will make animation on its rest - (from `200px - 400px`) ,

i.e  -

1. on start - `height:0px`
2. once clicked -

   2.1 `height:200px` immediatly

   2.2 `height:200px` to `height:400px` with transition .

How to get it ?

Comment: You will have to use keyframes in order to animate a transition with more than 2 states.

Comment: @Harry : That's the approach I tried to avoid from ;-)

Comment: Not a problem mate. I am removing that comment, please do not mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Add `min-height`

```
min-height: 200px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8bbo9cfz/2/

Comment: No, never use important. If you have to resort to this, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: sorry , you didn't get what I asked  .

Comment: @URL87: Actually this looks a better bet. You would probably have to add `opacity: 1` to the normal state and `opacity: 0` to the hidden state to kind of get the behavior that you need. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8bbo9cfz/3/) which is basically an add-on to the original answer.

Comment: You could also add `opacity` to the transition to make sure that first display bit doesn't appear like a full sudden jump. By the way +1 for a good option @GeorgeGarchagudashvili